# MySQL, How to Convert True/False to 1/0 in query

Tags: mysql, int, boolean

How do I convert boolean to integer in a MySQL query. I have tried numerous, things and have come up empty. I'm simply looking to convert the "value" column of true/false to 1 and 0 respectively into the "finalvalue" column. Please see link of screenshot.

MySQL Query:

```
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) as time_sec,
  topic as metric,
  data as value,
cast(DATA AS SIGNED) as finalvalue
FROM tcl_mqtt_log
WHERE topic = 'jace/home/heatpump/uvlight_ss';
```

[screenshot of mysql_query_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Qva.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you'll need to use a `CASE` expression here:

```
SELECT
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) AS time_sec,
    topic AS metric,
    data AS value,
    CASE WHEN data = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS finalvalue
FROM tcl_mqtt_log
WHERE topic = 'jace/home/heatpump/uvlight_ss';
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I tried using the case, but formatting is key here. I was close. Thanks again.